# How to loop through folders and rename files

Tags: ruby, file, rename

I am looping in folder like this

```
Dir.glob('**/*.tif').each do |image_file|
```

I get `images/SW/SW-9.tif` , i want to change to `images/SW/SW-9.png` and not duplicate, the .tif file should be deleted.

I want to rename all that files from .tif to .png

Answer (score 0):

`Dir.glob` returns the full path.

Step 1: gsub `.tif` to `.png`

Step 2: Check the new name isn't a duplicate

Step 3: Use `mv`

---

```
Dir.glob('./**/*.tif').each do |path|
  dest_path = path.gsub(".tif", ".png")
  unless File.exists?(dest_path)
    `mv "#{path}" "#{dest_path}"`
  end
end
```

---

edited with suggestion from comment

```
Dir.glob('./**/*.tif').each do |path|
  dest_path = path.gsub(/\.tif\z/, '.png')
  unless File.exists?(dest_path)
    File.rename(path, dest_path)
  end
end
```

Comment: `File.rename(path, dest_path)` instead of shelling out. Also, `gsub(/\.tif\Z/, '.png')` not to accidentally rename something other than the extension.

Comment: That should be `\z`, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: I tried that. i still have duplicate .tiff and also the path for new png files was outside of the folder

Comment: `gsub` is a tiny bit misguided since you should have only *one* file extension: use `sub` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Dir.glob('./**/*.tif').each { |img| File.rename(img, img.gsub(/tif$/, 'png')) unless File.exists?(img.gsub(/tif$/, 'png')) }
```

Comment: Worth splitting that up onto multiple lines so what's going on is more clear.